# Inserting Records From Csv File To Database Table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, csv, insert

What I need to do is to create a SQL Server Script to insert records from a CSV file to a table. I know that this can be done easily using "BULK Insert".

```
BULK
INSERT TempTable
FROM 'C:\Records.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Unfortunately, the CSV file contains inconsistent qualifiers ("). Some fields may or may not have this qualifiers when the CSV file is created (manually) like the sample below:

```
10001,LeBron Quitter,CompanyA
10002,"Insane, Charlie",CompanyB
10003,Donald Punk,"CompanyC,CA"
```

If I use the above code for the said CSV format, there will be errors because:
 1. Qualifier will be included in the table (Ex: "Insane)
 2. Since comma (,) is the fieldterminator, the 2nd record will be considered as 4 fields.

So I have to think of something else since I don't want to preprocess the CSV file. It came down to this solution - using MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0.

```
INSERT INTO MyRealTable
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0','Text;Database=C:\Temp\;','SELECT * FROM [Test.csv]')
```

Note: Before executing the above code be sure to have access right/permission & execute the following:

```
EXEC
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
Reconfigure
EXEC
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
Reconfigure
EXEC
sp_configure 'OLE Automation Procedures', 1;
Reconfigure
EXEC
sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1;
Reconfigure
```

Questions:
 1. Is my solution the right one?
 2. Are there any other better solution?
 3. Since I'm using MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4 solution, what should be installed/prerequisite?

I'm very open to any suggestion, criticism, or anything because I just want to learn more... Thanks you very much in advance...

Comment: Is this a one time insert or something that will occur regularly?

Comment: This will be done whenever the database administrator want to insert records in bulk. I don't think you can call that "regularly"... sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do this in SQL Server alone is probably quite a challenge - I would most like do this as a separate, stand-alone console app or something.

Basically, I'd use the excellent [FileHelpers 2.0 library](http://www.filehelpers.com) to handle the CSV import - works like a charm and is really easy to use. You can import any fixed-width or delimited file into a DataTable.

Once you have that, you can then turn around and use `SqlBulkCopy` from your app to bulk load these into SQL Server.

The code would look something like this:

```
// define your input record - what fields are there, how are the rows and
// fields delimited - the flexibility and power of FileHelpers is amazing!

[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class InputRecord
{
    public int ID;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string PersonName;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string CompanyName;
}

// in your console app, grab a file, import it into memory using FileHelpers,
// then convert it into a DataTable and use SqlBulkCopy to insert it into SQL Server
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // grab file name to import from command-line arguments
    string fileNameToImport = args[0];

    // instantiate FileHelpers engine
    FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(InputRecord));

    // read the data from the file into a DataTable
    DataTable records = engine.ReadFileAsDT(fileNameToImport);

    // create your SqlBulkCopy object
    SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy("server=(local);database=TEST;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

    bc.DestinationTableName = "TempTable";

    // bulk copy the data into SQL Server
    bc.WriteToServer(records);
}
```

Comment: thanks marc_s! but looking at my last solution (note: it is required to execute this using just a script), do you think it is enough?